# Declare object as not dirty in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

There are a lot of post on how to do this, but none of them could solve my problem.

I have an `PreLoadEventListener` which sets specified attributes or collections to null if a user has no permissions to it.

```
public void OnPreLoad(PreLoadEvent @event)
    {
        if (// I check permission here)
        {
            int index = 0;

            // Set values to null if user is not permitted
            foreach (object obj in @event.State)
            {
                @event.State.SetValue(null, index);

                index++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Let's say something like:

```
public class Employee {
    private virtual int Id {get;set}
    private virtual string Name {get;set;}
    private virtual List<Document> Documents {get;set;}
}

public class Document {
    private virtual int Id {get;set;};
    private virtual byte[] Binary {get;set;}
}
```

Now I say that there are no permissions on `Documents` but on the rest there are read permissions.

NHibernate now thinks the null values of `Documents` is a dirty object and saves the null values into the database.

I also have a custom FindDirty() and PreFlush() method that check if user is not permitted and then mark it as not dirty. **BUT** they don't seem to be called on the Get of an entity.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Marking the entity as readonly might help. But please, please consider taking the @AmitJoshi's advice

```
public void OnPreLoad(PreLoadEvent @event)
{
    if (/* Check permission here */)
    {
        int index = 0;

        // Set values to null if user is not permitted
        foreach (object obj in @event.State)
        {
            @event.State.SetValue(null, index);

            index++;
        }

        @event.Session.SetReadOnly(@event.Entity, true); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. Now I'm getting the error `NHibernate.HibernateException: instance was not in a valid state`... any idea?

Comment: Or without that requirement, can you give me an example how you would solve this problem?

Comment: Doing that on post load probably would help. Also, you should not mess with the "State" of the entity, as it is internal. There is `Entity` property on the `event` object, change it there.